# How to test ipa file using calabash-ios in mac OS?

Tags: ios, calabash

First time i am working on mac OS X in this i need to install any sample ipa file and test using calabash-ios as like calabash-android.Usually in calabash-android we will download apk file and signed it then install apk file in android device.Then we will start create scenario using cucumber. But in calabash-ios i don't know how to install ipa file in iphone. I have searched in net they are giving sample project which already created by xcode. Here my concern is how to install and test external ipa file using calabash-ios mobile automation tool.  Please let me know  if any one know the answer for this question. Thanks in advance..

Answer (score 3):

You cannot test with an .ipa file if it does not include calabash-ios framework inside it. The reason being in android, you have a seperate instrumentation server that acts as a test server. In IOS, the test server is part of the app and you cannot test it without building the .ipa file with the framework. If you are using XCode, then there are commands that would set it up automatically for you. But if you are using Xamarin(Monotouch), you have to force load the calabash framework. So if you are getting an .ipa file from someone you have to get it loaded with the framework.

Here is a blog post that describes setting up calabash-ios for xamarin.
http://programmersjunk.blogspot.com/2013/07/calabash-ios-on-xamarin-studio.html

Answer (score 0):

For this question we have answer in below link,

https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/calabash-ios/m4hsmoBPLUo